# why my image is not transparent, whereas I am using imagecolortransparent ()

Tags: php, transparent

I want a picture of a crown covering the woman's head, and the woman's face is visible. Help me
My code is:

```
// First we create our stamp image manually from GD
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('http://depictfoll.net/face/php-facedetection-master/Untitled-2_clipped_rev_1 (1).png');
    $black = imagecolorallocate($this->canvas, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($this->canvas, $black);

    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
    $marge_right = 0;
    $marge_bottom = 0;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);


    // Merge the stamp onto our photo with an opacity of 50%
    imagecopymerge($this->canvas, $stamp, $this->face['x']+$this->face['w'] - $sx - $marge_right, $this->face['y']+ $this->face['w'] - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 100);
    //$color = imagecolorallocate($this->canvas, 33333, 0, 0); //red

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($this->canvas);
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following is how this worked for me :)

First check if your new image is created as true color:

```
$this->canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
```

Then do following to your new image:

```
imagesavealpha($this->canvas, true);
imagealphablending($this->canvas, false);

$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->canvas, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($this->canvas , 0, 0, $background);
```

Basically here you set alpha channel for your new image and fill this with transparent colour. Then you can copy your stuff over this keeping transparency.